# `axios` not loading : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, axios, webpacker

I have created a rails application using `webpacker` and added `react` application to it. Then I added axios using yarn and I see that it is installed in `node_modules` folder. Now I am trying to initialise using following code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})
```

After I run `./bin/webpack-dev-server` and running rails app in browser. I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` error and my react app is breaking.

Comment: have u installed `axios` package?

Comment: Yes I have installed